"Currently running a version of TypeScript which is not officially supported by @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree" problem after Nuxt updating
I've just upgraded nuxt in my project with npx nuxi upgrade and now when I run eslint . I have this output
=============

WARNING: You are currently running a version of TypeScript which is not officially supported by @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree.

You may find that it works just fine, or you may not.

SUPPORTED TYPESCRIPT VERSIONS: >=4.3.5 <5.4.0

YOUR TYPESCRIPT VERSION: 5.4.3

Please only submit bug reports when using the officially supported version.

=============

I've found out that an older version of nuxt uses "@nuxt/eslint-config": "^0.2.0" to configure ESLint. You can look at its configuration here.
As you can see in the code it depends on @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin, @typescript-eslint/parser and then I looked at the package-lock.json and this "@nuxt/eslint-config" package.
Here is the package config:
package-lock.json
"node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config": {
         "version": "0.2.0",
         "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@nuxt/eslint-config/-/eslint-config-0.2.0.tgz",
         "integrity": "sha512-NeJX8TLcnNAjQFiDs3XhP+9CHKK8jaKsP7eUyCSrQdgY7nqWe7VJx64lwzx5FTT4cW3RHMEyH+Y0qzLGYYoa/A==",
         "dev": true,
         "dependencies": {
            "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.3.3",
            "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.5.0",
            "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.5.0",
            "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
            "typescript": "^5.2.2"
         },
         "peerDependencies": {
            "eslint": "^8.48.0"
         }
      },

There's 6.5.0 version of @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and @typescript-eslint/parser. But the latest one is 7.5.0. So, nuxt updated typescript by npx nuxi upgrade but didn't update @nuxt/eslint-config. Actually there's no newer version of it :)

The best way to fix it is to use npm install -D @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser --legacy-peer-deps
--legacy-peer-deps install your packages on top of the dependency tree and you won't see any conflicts.

This helped me to resolve similiar error in project created in Vuetify 3.6.X version. I had TS warning after using npm run lint in almost pure project, so everyone else - if you have similiar error I would recommend to try this solution. Thanks!
